# Filter/Map composition problem Haskell

Tags: haskell, composition

I've been given this question in a tutorial, and I really don't know how to go about it.

> How must g and h be defined in terms of p and f in order to ensure that
>   `filter p . map f = map g . filter h`
>   always holds?

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is clear that `f :: a -> b` and `p :: b -> Bool`. Since we cannot make any other assumptions about `f` and `g`, one will have to define

```
h = p . f
g = f
```

Now `h :: a -> Bool` and `g :: a -> b`.

Answer (score 4):

Think about types.

```
f :: a -> b
g :: a -> b
p :: b -> Bool
h :: a -> Bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see this:

`map g (filter h A)` is the set `{g(a) : with h(a) is true and a is elt from A}`

`filter p (map f A)` is the set `{f(a) : with p(f(a) is true and a is elt from A}`

For these sets to be equal we must choose `f = g` and `h(a) = p(f(a))`.